# Chat Option for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have to implement chatting functionality for iphone (login basis).I dont have any clear cut idea most of the sample code will support macos supported framework

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMPP / Jabber`, `IRC`, `SILC` protocol to get chat functionality for your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use XMPP as the previous answer suggested i would recommend trying out
http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/